# react native iOS can't open Camera/Gallery after first time

Tags: ios, react-native

This is my source code:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isVisible: false,
    };
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({isVisible: true});
  }

  openPicker = () => {
    this.setState({isVisible: false});
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      mediaType: "video",
    }).then((video) => {
      console.log(video);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openModal}>
          <Text>Choose Image</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {
          this.state.isVisible &&
          <Modal style={styles.modal}>
            <View style={styles.conModal}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touch} onPress={this.openPicker}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Open Gallery</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When user tap "Choose Image" button, app will show "Choose Image" modal which allow user choose "Open Gallery" button or other buttons such as "Open Camera",...

After user choose "Open Gallery" button, app will close "Choose Image" modal by `this.setState({isVisible: false})` before open Gallery.

It's working perfectly on Android. But it only work once time on iOS. Next time, app also show Gallery but it's closed immediately.

If i change logic to: open Gallery before close "Choose Image" modal by `this.setState({isVisible: false})`, it will work. But my customer don't accept it.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and didn't understand the cause till I read your question.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

open gallery after some delay. I think it may work

```
openPicker = () => {
    this.setState({isVisible: false});
 // open gallery after some delay.
    setTimeout(()=>{
       ImagePicker.openPicker({
       mediaType: "video",
    }).then((video) => {
       console.log(video);
    });
    },700) // you can change delay time as per your requirement

}
```

Comment: I know this solution. But android work perfectly without setTimeout. And i want to know why.